# Self referenced has_many and deleting join records when any side of relation is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Board` model. Each `Board` can be `Source` for other `Board`. This relationship is saved in `Feed` table.

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feeds, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sources, through: :feeds

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :user_id

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  belongs_to :source, class_name: "Board"

  attr_accessible :board_id, :source_id

end
```

When I destroy `Board` record, then it destroys corresponding `feeds`. But how to do this the same but for `source` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `:dependent => :destroy` too?

Read [Deleting from associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html): has_many, has_one and belongs_to associations support the :dependent option

If that doesn't work you might also be able to use a ActiveRecord Callbacks:

```
after_destroy do |record| 
 other = BoardsSources.find_by_board_id_and_source_id(record.board_id, record.source_id)
 other.destroy if other
end
```

Comment: But where? If i put it here `has_many :sources, through: :feeds` it will remove related `board` not the relaton `feed` record, right?

Comment: could you try doing it with AR callbacks? I updated my answer

Comment: I made it using callbacks: `after_destroy {|board| Feed.destroy_all "source_id = #{board.id}"}`. Thanks for help.